# finding the last visible row in a ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to find the Sheet.Row of the last visible row in a ListObject. It seems to work fine but am wondering if there might be a quicker way to do this when the ListObject is very large.

Cheers

```
Function GetLastDataRowNumber(aListObj As ListObject, Optional bVisibleOnly As Boolean = True) As Long
CheckArgNotNothing aListObj, "aListObj"

Dim k As Long: k = aListObj.ListRows.Count
Dim lstRow As ListRow: Set lstRow = aListObj.ListRows(k)

GetLastDataRowNumber = lstRow.range.Row

If bVisibleOnly Then
    Do Until (lstRow.range.EntireRow.Hidden = False)
        k = k - 1
        If k = 0 Then
            ' no visible rows at all
            GetLastDataRowNumber = 0
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set lstRow = aListObj.ListRows(k)
    Loop
    GetLastDataRowNumber = lstRow.range.Row
End If
```

End Function

**UPDATE**

I had to revisit this sorry subject today. My original code worked, but not always and not efficiently with very big tables. Looking for RowHeight=0 is an upgrade from rare but occasional failures when trying to get Range.EntireRow.Hidden. Below is better working code:

```html
'modified from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/593611-find-last-row-filtered-data.html
Function LastFilteredRowFor(anLo As ListObject) As Long
On Error GoTo NoFilterOnSheet
    With anLo.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1)
        Dim rngVisible As Range: Set rngVisible = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        LastFilteredRowFor = GetLastRowNbrFromSpecialCells(rngVisible.Address, anLo.ShowTotals)
    End With
NoFilterOnSheet:
End Function

Function GetLastRowNbrFromSpecialCells(anAddr As String, bHasTotalRow As Boolean) As Long
    Dim v As Variant: v = Split(Replace(anAddr, ",", ":"), ":")
    Dim k As Long: k = UBound(v)
    Dim sLastWord As String: sLastWord = v(k)
    If k = 0 Or (Not bHasTotalRow) Then
        If bHasTotalRow Then
            GetLastRowNbrFromSpecialCells = 0 'the word *is* the TotalRow, not what we want
        Else
            GetLastRowNbrFromSpecialCells = Range(sLastWord).Row
        End If
    Else
        Dim sLastDelim As String: sLastDelim = Mid(Right$(anAddr, Len(sLastWord) + 1), 1, 1)
        Select Case sLastDelim
            Case ":"
                GetLastRowNbrFromSpecialCells = Range(sLastWord).Offset(-1).Row
            Case ","
                GetLastRowNbrFromSpecialCells = Range(v(k - 1)).Row
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop if the range of hidden rows is contiguous and at the end of the table:

```
Public Function GetLastDataRowNumber(ByRef aListObj As ListObject) As Long

    GetLastDataRowNumber = aListObj.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

End Function
```

.

else, try accessing row height property directly (**lstRow.Range.Height <> 0**):

```
Public Function GetLastDataRowNumber(ByRef aListObj As ListObject, _
                                     Optional ByVal bVisibleOnly As Boolean = True) As Long

    CheckArgNotNothing aListObj, "aListObj"

    Dim k As Long, lstRow As ListRow

    k = aListObj.ListRows.Count
    Set lstRow = aListObj.ListRows(k)
    GetLastDataRowNumber = lstRow.Range.Row
    If bVisibleOnly Then
        Do Until (lstRow.Range.Height <> 0)
            k = k - 1
            If k = 0 Then
                GetLastDataRowNumber = 0
                Exit Function
            End If
            Set lstRow = aListObj.ListRows(k)
        Loop
        GetLastDataRowNumber = lstRow.Range.Row
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: Looks like the same loop perf-wise, no? The hidden rows could be anywhere a filter op puts them and unlikely to ever be contiguous. Cheers

Comment: performance might improve a bit if you check row height (I haven't tested it with a large table though)